# Errors on installing Expo CLI

Tags: node.js, npm

When I simply run

```sh
npm install -g expo-cli
```

I get a whole list of errors I don't understand (below). What are these errors and warnings about? How do I prevent them?

---

- macOS 11.6.4
- npm 8.6.0
- node 16.14.2
- corepack 0.10.0
- expo-cli 5.3.0
- ios-sim 9.0.0
- npm 8.6.0
- react-devtools 4.24.3

---

```sh
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.8: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@3.0.0: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead

added 2 packages, changed 1556 packages, and audited 1559 packages in 2m

115 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

24 vulnerabilities (11 moderate, 13 high)
```

Answer (score 0):

NPM warns you that the package you've installed depends on a lot of outdated packages.
The installation went just fine.

If you run `npm list -g | grep expo-cli` you should get something like this:

```
+-- expo-cli@5.3.0
```

`npm list -g` lists all the global packages installed. `| grep <some-package>` only shows the results that match .

Preventing the warnings should be the job of the package maintainer. The only thing you can do is to [update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-update) the package and its dependencies and hope that it still works.

Most of the time you don't really have to care about those warnings. Most NPM packages available have some sort of warning. What could be a bigger issue, is the amount of [vulnerabilities](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities) in these packages. But they might not be important if you are just getting started with NPM.